# hide/show laterally col-4 (aproximately) div/element in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

what is the best way to make in bootstrap a hide/show element like in the picture??
I started with something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding-left">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 no-padding-left">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 background-azul-claro">
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                        <a href=""><img src="assets/images/ic_close_white_36dp_1x.png" alt=""> </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 text-center" style="">
                        <h3>Nueva incidencia</h3> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                        <a href=""><img src="assets/images/ic_done_white_36dp_1x.png" alt=""> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-left"> <img src="assets/images/default-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-left background-azul-oscuro"> <img src="" alt=""> </div>
            <!-- form div with form field -->
            <!-- checkbox Mostrar otras incidencias -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
.background-azul-oscuro {
    background-color: #009688;
}
.background-azul-claro {
    background-color: #00BFA5;
}
.no-padding-left {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
h3 {
    color: white;
}
```

It´s nested columns the best way to do it ???
Im using angular in the front end, should i use normal bootstrap or angular ui bootstrap???
I would like totally responsible element with the hide and show functionality..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you would have to use **custom width, margin and padding** for the default bootstrap col's, there isn't much sense in using them.

You could have something like this in my opinion:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-azul-claro">
   //  position:relative;
       width: calc(100% - 40px);
       margin-right: 40px;  
       float: left;
  </div

  <div class=" background-azul-oscuro">
   // position: relative;
      width: 40px;
      float: right;
  </div>
</div>
```

*In case you would want one div to hover above the other, you should use `position: absolute;`